# PHP How to edit database entry I just created? (basic)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

In my site, I have a page to create an site page (addpage.php) and then send the user to a listing of all pages (pages.php), from which they can click on the page they'd like to edit (editpage.php).

I do this because my editpage.php uses the page_id variable to select the page's info from the database and I don't know how to select that variable without first going to pages.php to list all those variables.

I'd like to be able to complete addpage.php and then GO DIRECTLY to editpage.php - but how do I select the page_id that will only just be created on the insert into the database?

My code on addpage.php is basically

```
$q = "INSERT INTO pages (page_name, page_content) VALUES ('$name', '$content' )";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { // If it ran OK.
            // send to pages.php
        } else { // If it did not run OK.
            echo '<p>The page has NOT been added</p>';
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q = "INSERT INTO pages (page_name, page_content) VALUES ('$name', '$content' )";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
$id=mysql_insert_id();

   if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { // If it ran OK.
        // send to pages.php
    } else { // If it did not run OK.
        echo '<p>The page has NOT been added</p>';
    }
```

You can check [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

Comment: Thanks for adding this code - though it gave me an error about not being able to connect to the database? I don't know why- the variables passed into the database.

Comment: This is the solution (the `mysql_insert_id()` bit). Your error of not being able to connect is an error generated by an earlier call to `mysql_connect`. Make sure that information is correct before you try the `mysql_insert_id()` comment.

Comment: had to adjust mysql to mysqli and add the database connection in the () - but this method worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a query to your database, asking what've been the last inserted id. You can do this running this query:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as lastId
```

Then you get the value as you do with any regular query (because this *is* a regular query actually).

In php there's a function called [mysql-insert-id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) which is more elgant.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mysql, you can get the ID of the last insert by running the following query `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. This will get you the ID.

Comment: If I'm using this, do I have to do what I'd normally do for a mysql query and specify a table and then echo the output in a loop?